# Turn iterable into iterator

Tags: php, iterator, iterable, php-7.1

In PHP 7.1 a new [`iterable` pseudo-type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php) was introduced.

Is there a straightforward way to transform a generic `iterable` into an `Iterator`? Or should I use something like

```
if (is_array($iterable)) {
    return new \ArrayIterator($iterable);
}

return new \IteratorIterator($iterable);
```

Comment: `$iterator = (function() use ($iterable) { yield from $iterable; })()` ^^